# Why this code works ? memcpy on a constant array

Tags: c, pointers, constants, function-declaration, qualifiers

The parameters for `memcpy` are `memcpy(void *_Dst, const void *_Src, size_t _Size)`

But with the following code, I pass a constant array as parameter '_Src' and it still copy the content of the array into the destination, even though I didn't pass a `const void *`.

```
int tab[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    
memcpy(tab, (int[3]) { 7, 8, 9 }, sizeof(int) * 3);
    
printf("%d %d %d \n", tab[0], tab[1], tab[2]); // Output: 7 8 9
```

Does the expression `(int[3]) { 7, 8, 9 }` returns a pointer to the first element of the array?

Comment: I suspect that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay answers your question.

Comment: Or maybe you are asking why passing non-`const` pointer as a `const` pointer is OK? Or why `int` is converted to `void`? Which point is confusing you?

Comment: The compound literal is an array. Like all arrays, it decays to a pointer when passed to a function. The wording of your question is not pedantically correct, but *"a pointer to the first element"* is indeed being passed to the function.

Comment: "compound literal" like `(int[3]) { 7, 8, 9 }` are **not** `const`. You can write `(int[3]) { 7, 8, 9 }[1] = 42` and it is perfectly defined by C standard, though the utility is questionable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
(int[3]) { 7, 8, 9 }
```

is a compound literal of the type `int[3]` that used as a function argument is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element.

On the other hand (The C Standard, 6.3.2.3 Pointers)

> 1 A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any
> object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a
> pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the
> original pointer.

and

> 2 For any qualifier q, a pointer to a non-q-qualified type may be
> converted to a pointer to the q-qualified version of the type; the
> values stored in the original and converted pointers shall compare
> equal.

So in this call

```
memcpy(tab, (int[3]) { 7, 8, 9 }, sizeof(int) * 3);
```

the compound literal is converted at first to a pointer of the type `int *` to its first element that then is converted to the type `void *` according to the first quote and then to the type `const void *` according to the second quote.

The qualifier `const` means that the pointed object will not be changed within the function. It does not mean that the expression used as an argument is a constant expression.

Answer (score 4):

When a function's parameter is declared as a pointer to a `const` type, it "prevents" the function from modifying what the pointer points to (i.e. not through the parameter itself, but it could with a cast), but it doesn't restrict the actual parameter type to be `const`.

A variable of non-`const` qualified type may be safely converted to a `const` qualified type.  This is allowed as per section 6.3.2.3p2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> For any  qualifier *q*, a pointer  to  a  non-*q*-qualified  type  may
> be  converted  to  a  pointer  to the *q*-qualified version of the
> type; the values stored in the original and converted pointers shall
> compare equal

Comment: `const` at best suggests a function will not change the object; it does not prevent it. `void foo(const int *p) { * (int *) p = 0; } int main(void) { int x = 1; foo(&x); return x; }` is strictly conforming C code that exits with success.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Without the cast, ```*p = 0``` results in a compilation error. Isn't that preventing a change? I know there's plenty of ways to change something without the compiler knowing it, I'm just trying to understand the implication that ```const``` is nearly meaningless.

Comment: @sj95126: The fact that different code, `*p = 0`, results in no change being made because the compiler objects, does not alter the fact that `* (int *) p = 0` does compile and does change the value. Since the value can be changed by the function, it is false that `const` **prevents** the function from changing the value. It may hinder the function from changing the value by requiring some additional code, but ultimately it does not prevent it. This is somewhat due to the history of C development; `const` was added late, and it is largely a programmer aid, not a control…

Comment: … Thus, using `const` on the type a function parameter points to suggests to the function caller that the object will not be changed through that parameter and assists the function author in not changing it accidentally by causing compiler diagnostics if they attempt such a change without using a cast. But that is largely all it is in this usage, just an aid, not an absolute prevention. If an object is originally **defined** with `const`, especially if it is static, then the system **may** put it in read-only memory and prevent a program from modifying it. But that is a different use case.